# Dynamically inserted javascript function arg fails with string value but works with number argument

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically insert some html + inline javascript into a page using jquery and javascript.  In the markup + code I'm inserting I'm trying to add the value I receive via an ajax call as the argument to the inline function.

The following fails if key is a string:

```
$.each(data.report, function(key, val) {
  // ...    
  html_to_return = "<button onclick='submit_query(" + key + ")'>Submit</button>";
}
```

with the message: `Can't find variable: ACTUALVALUEOFKEY`.

However, if I set key to a number, the following works:

```
var key = 0;
html_to_return = "<button onclick='submit_query(" + key + ")'>Submit</button>";
// elsewhere:
function submit_query(id_key) {
  console.log("value of id_key: " + id_key);
}
```

It successfully logs 0 to the console.

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do above?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. Try to isolate the problem and share it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: the problem is that `submit_query(3)` is ok js while `submit_query(mykeyname)` is not (when mykeyname is undefined); depending of what you want quotes are a solution: `submit_query('mykeyname')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the content.

```
$.each(data.report, function(key, val) {
    // ...    
    html_to_return = "<button onclick='submit_query(\"" + key + "\")'>Submit</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code is that if the data comes form an untrusted source (like registered usernames in a database), it will allow HTML injection.

Your code will generate the following snippets:

```
# key = 3
<button onclick='submit_query(3)'>Submit</button>
# works well

# key = "alma"
<button onclick='submit_query(alma)'>Submit</button>
# it tries to access a variable named `alma` instead of string literal "alma"

# key = "'></button><script>alert('pwned')</script><button value='"
<button onclick=''></button><script>alert('pwned')</script><button value=''>Submit</button>
# full html injection
```

To prevent these, you must properly convert values to literals (for example using `JSON.stringify`) and escape the result.

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
     .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
     .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
     .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
     .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
     .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

// ...

var key = 0;
html_to_return = '<button onclick="submit_query(' + escapeHtml(JSON.stringify(key)) + ')">Submit</button>';

// elsewhere:
function submit_query(id_key) {
  console.log("value of id_key: " + id_key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The data is coming from a trusted source but just to be safe in case I'm missing something I'll implement this.

Comment: You have to escape after JSON.stringify anyway because it will potentially contain quotes. So if already escaping, why not to escape all html? :)